# npm test fails for custom yeoman generator

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have built a custom yeoman generator. You can find the code at https://github.com/abhishekoza/generator-ratchet.

When I try "npm test", I get following error

```
  1 passing (454ms)
  1 failing


1) ratchet generator creates expected files:
     Uncaught Error: You don't seem to have a generator with the name mocha:app installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 1 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
The command "npm test" exited with 1.
```

For full build log, url is "s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/26049613/log.txt"

I have added "generator-mocha" as peerDependency in package.json. But when I use, "npm install", it does not install, so I added it under "dependency". "generator-mocha" is installed now, but still I am getting above error.

To build this custom generator, I referred https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the [`test.js` in the `generator-webapp`](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/test/test.js) and found that they have an additional bit in the `createGenerator` call within the `beforeEach`.  Try modifying your `test-creation.js`, around line 13, to this:

```
this.app = helpers.createGenerator('ratchet:app', [
    '../../app', [
        helpers.createDummyGenerator(),
        'mocha:app'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: That worked. Can you tell me what does this code do?

Comment: Those two lines create a mock generator and name it 'mocha:app', which was the generator needed for your tests.  If you want to see how it does that, check out the `createGenerator` code here: https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/test/helpers.js#L226-L268 which takes in an Array containing the generators.  This code appears to be written to help you test your geneators, creating mocks to avoid having to actually include the real ones.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this issue was resolved, there may be another cause for this problem:
https://github.com/yeoman/generator-generator/issues/46

The folder containing the generator must begin with "generator-".
For instance, if you generator is called my-generator, then the folder should be called generator-my-generator.
It's a bit awkward, because after running npm link, I could use my generator by running "yo my-generator", but running npm test failed (until I renamed the folder).

Hope it would help others in the future...